# JavaScript String Troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, where-clause

I've got a set of checkboxes that, when checked, should populate the associated points on a map.

This works great:

```
var type_column = "FastFood";
var searchType = type_column + " IN (-1,";
if ( $("#divType1").is(':checked')) searchType += "1,";
if ( $("#divType2").is(':checked')) searchType += "2,";
if ( $("#divType3").is(':checked')) searchType += "3,";
if ( $("#divType4").is(':checked')) searchType += "4,";
whereClause += " AND " + searchType.slice(0, searchType.length - 1) + ")";
```

But this doesn't:

```
var type_column = "FastFood";
var searchType = type_column + " IN (-1,";
if ( $("#divType1").is(':checked')) searchType += "Arbys,";
if ( $("#divType2").is(':checked')) searchType += "Burgerking,";
if ( $("#divType3").is(':checked')) searchType += "Checkers,";
if ( $("#divType4").is(':checked')) searchType += "Dairyqueen,";
whereClause += " AND " + searchType.slice(0, searchType.length - 1) + ")";
```

Changing "Arbys" to "a" (and so on) also doesn't work, so it's not about the number of characters. I've also tried putting in a set of single quotes around the string that doesn't include the comma. (Sadly, just using the numbers isn't an option for other, unrelated reasons.)

Comment: Offtopic: Hopefully this runs not serversided or you validate this query serversided, too. Otherwise this is a big possible mysql injection. :-)

Comment: You mean you have tried: `searchType += "'Arbys',";` and so on?

Comment: No, I mean that your script may contain some big security issues when you are about to create a mysql query client based that is executed on the server without any further validation.

Comment: Understood, thanks. (codingbiz wasn't person asking question.) And yes, codingbiz, exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `substring` instead of `slice`. `slice` is for arrays, not for strings.

Answer (score 0):

At all, your solution is very hacky. You should build the query **not** on client side. Apart of this, the following code may be *better* solution for you:

```
var type_column = "FastFood";
var whereClause = [];
if ( $("#divType1").is(':checked')) whereClause.push("Arbys");
if ( $("#divType2").is(':checked')) whereClause.push("Burgerking");
if ( $("#divType3").is(':checked')) whereClause.push("Checkers");
if ( $("#divType4").is(':checked')) whereClause.push("Dairyqueen");

whereClause += " AND " + type_column + " IN ('" + whereClause.join('\',\'') + "')";
```

Comment: This works, thanks, but how would I fix this, which now no longer works?
`getList: function(whereClause) {
var selectColumns = "Address, Food ";
MapsLib.query(selectColumns, whereClause, "MapsLib.displayList");
`},`

Comment: Solved this on my own. Solution, for future searchers, was just to substitute "whereClause" for a new variable in above code for all but one instance (second-to-last one). Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add the search strings to an array. That way you dont need to worry about having a string like "Arbys," with a comma at the end and then stripping the last character, instead you can join the array using the comma as a delimiter:

```
var type_column = "FastFood";
var searchType = type_column + " IN (-1,";
var search_array = [];
if ( $("#divType1").is(':checked')) searchArray.push("Arbys");
if ( $("#divType2").is(':checked')) searchArray.push("Burgerking");
if ( $("#divType3").is(':checked')) searchArray.push("Checkers");
if ( $("#divType4").is(':checked')) searchArray.push("Dairyqueen");
whereClause += " AND " + searchType + searchArray.join(',') + ")";
```

Comment: wow, someone just addded basically the same code while i wrote this :)